# Software to Build a Selenium POM

Tags: selenium2, c#

I have a basic script that parses through HTML and creates a basic POM based on Inputs, Selects etc. It does a decent job but I was curious if there is any 'professional' or popularly used pieces that offers similar functionality?

This is for C# with Selenium 2 using the PageFactory.

Comment: Why generate the POM? Are you really going to use all elements in your tests? Sounds a bit like overkill, think YAGNI! :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Comment: Forms with 50+ required elements are a drain to write out a POM with by hand.

Comment: Damn, lot of fields! :) Not sure I would want to be a user of a system like that though. Goodluck in finding your solution, but I do not think it exists, because generating paths or selectors doesn't sound very maintainable and will need a lot of manual work anyways. Better is to give to form fields logical selector/ID's so it is easy to code when making selenium tests.

Comment: They all have IDs, for the most part at least. My current solution gets me 90% of the way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but there's a Chrome Extension called [Selenium Page Object Generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-page-object-gene/epgmnmcjdhapiojbohkkemlfkegmbebb?hl=en-US) that looks like it automates PO creation, and it supports C#.

[SWD Page Recorder](https://github.com/dzharii/swd-recorder) also automates PO creation, and supports C#.

Comment: The Chrome extension just sits there trying to process everything. I will see if I can limit down the elements some soon. The SWD seems decent overall but I seem to have to manually select and name all of the elements I want. Will be useful when having people assist me with it.

Answer (score 1):

My current Solution. Parses through the HTML file (C:\QA\Test.html), finds all input tags and Select tags, if they have an ID it will convert them into a POM based format. It then prints out to C:\QA\Pom.txt the basic object for it.

Overall, it does 90% of the work that I need, with minor editing.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using CsQuery;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = CQ.CreateDocumentFromFile(@"C:\QA\Test.html");
        var inputFields = doc["input"]; 
        var inputPairs = inputFields.Select(node => new Tuple<string, string>(node.Id, node.Value));
        string pom = String.Empty;
        foreach (var pair in inputPairs)
        {
            var split = pair.Item1.Split('_');
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Item1.Trim()))
            {
                pom += String.Format("[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = \"{0}\")]\r\n", pair.Item1);
                pom += String.Format("public IWebElement {0};\r\n\r\n", split[split.Length - 1]);
            }
        }

        var selectFields = doc["select"]; 
        var selectPairs = selectFields.Select(node => new Tuple<string, string>(node.Id, node.Value));
        foreach (var pair in selectPairs)
        {
            var split = pair.Item1.Split('_');
            var name = split[split.Length - 1];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Item1.Trim()))
            {
                pom += String.Format("[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = \"{0}\")]\r\n", pair.Item1);
                pom += String.Format(@"public IWebElement {0}Element;
                                        public SelectElement {0}
                                        {{
                                            get {{ return new SelectElement({0}Element); }}
                                        }} {1}{1}{1}", name,Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\QA\Pom.txt", pom);
    }
}
```